חיריק before ם at the end of a word
There are certain words in the Torah that one would expect to end in ים, but are spelled without the י (One example is שְִׂעִירִם).
I try to make a distinction between long and short vowels, such as between חיריק מלא and חיריק חסר. How should I pronounce the vowel in these words? Is it a long חיריק, like in the “normal” version of this suffix that is spelled with a י? Or is it a short חיריק, as might be indicated by the חסר spelling?
Edit: Side question—would the answer also apply to cases of a missing Yud after khiriq that are NOT part of the ים suffix? Or are those different?

Update! Learned more about the history of Hebrew and got my answer: it's indeed a long hiriq. I'm leaving the question up for others.

https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/306/759

@Qwertrl why not answer your own question?

First of all, long and short vowels are a later concept of medieval grammarians. Moreover, long vowels can be written both with full and defective spelling, although the latter are less typical.

@Kazibácsi Could you explain the first sentence of your comment?

The concept of short and long vowels can be traced back to the 12th century grammarian R' Yosef Kimchi and his book Seifer Zikaron. This is a clear Arabic influence, and the earlier Masoretes didn't have such terminology.

@Kazibácsi Sure, but they still existed. The fact that categorizing vowels into long and short variants wasn’t yet considered, doesn’t mean long vowels didn’t exist. There’s a reason Arabic linguistic theorists invented that manner of categorization: It’s because long vowels existed already.

But it doesn't have to do anything with the spelling, which is a much earlier tradition. There are words written in a defective spelling, yet containing a long vowel – you've just found one! Another example is דִבֵּר in Bemidbar 12:2, where the chiriq is definitely long despite lacking the letter י.

@Kazibácsi I agree with your comment, except the last part: Why would the Chiriq in that example be long?

You should probably read it long. Some khiriqs are supposed to be long like the י in הפעיל (though even this is controversial) and all the masculine plural endings. The first khiriq in הפעיל and most khiriqs that need to to be in a closed syllable are short.

I would compare it to וַיִּירְאוּ, which, according to the Radak, should be pronounced with a long chiriq whether or not it has two yuds, when the intention is fear as opposed to sight.
